# Spring integration move file after produce message to kafka

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

First of all you can find my code at https://github.com/keiseithunder/spring-sftp-xml-to-json/blob/main/src/main/java/com/demo/sftp/SftpApplication.java

I have a spring integration that read file from SFTP server into a stream and send to kafka and then trying to move a remote file to other directory in the same remote server after succesfully produce the message. But, **the file doesn't move at all and didn't throw any error**.

I have try using this code to move a file from `upload/test.xml` (the file in `upload/file/test.xml` is a backup that I use to copy to `upload` directory) to `upload/processed/test.xml`.

```java
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "success")
  public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "");
  }
```

I already set `file_renameTo=upload/processed/test.xml` in the `headers`. Not sure, what I do wrong. Or there is a way to use something like `advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("@template.copy(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'])");` to move a file?

**My Message is**

```
"GenericMessage [payload=Note(to=Toves, from=Jani, heading=Reminder, body=Don't forget me this weekend!!!!!), headers={file_remoteHostPort=localhost:2222, file_remoteFileInfo={"directory":false,"filename":"test.xml","link":false,"modified":1674550080000,"permissions":"rw-r--r--","remoteDirectory":"upload","size":122}, kafka_messageKey=test.xml, file_remoteDirectory=upload, kafka_recordMetadata=test-0@298, file_renameTo=upload/processed/test.xml, id=708d04c4-5abc-9f45-e83b-1fea7ffa5e8d, closeableResource=org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession@2e0aa05, file_remoteFile=test.xml, timestamp=1674556856288}]"
```

PS. I have try using debugger to see what wrong and found that it seem to raise an error at

```java
    private String obtainRemoteFilePath(Message<?> requestMessage) {
Error here----> String remoteFilePath = this.fileNameProcessor.processMessage(requestMessage);
        Assert.state(remoteFilePath != null,
                () -> "The 'fileNameProcessor' evaluated to null 'remoteFilePath' from message: " + requestMessage);
        return remoteFilePath;
    }
```

"class com.demo.sftp.models.Note cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.demo.sftp.models.Note is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @387f9ed2; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

EDIT 1: Add solution

1. need to define an InboundChannelAdapter as PublishSubscribeChannel like

```java
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel streamChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
  }
```

2. Then add OutboundGateway as the LOWEST_PRECEDENCE order like

```java
  @Bean
  @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "streamChannel")
  public MessageHandler moveFile() {
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), Command.MV.getCommand(),
        "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + headers['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway
        .setRenameExpressionString(
            "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/processed/' +headers['timestamp'] + '-' + headers['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(false);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setUseTemporaryFileName(true);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setAsync(true);
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
  }
```

3. Extra: in case we want to move the file that have error(from errorChannel). We need to change `setRenameExpressionString` to match the `ErrorMessage` structure. Eg.

```java
  @Bean
  @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
  public MessageHandler moveErrorFile() {
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), Command.MV.getCommand(),
        "payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway
        .setRenameExpressionString(
            "payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/error/' + payload['failedMessage']['headers']['timestamp'] + '-' + payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(false);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setUseTemporaryFileName(true);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setAsync(true);
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
  }
```

Comment: This seem related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631412/spring-integration-sftp-rename-or-move-file-in-remote-server-after-copying?rq=1 
gonna try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [artem-bilan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan) answer in [Spring integration - SFTP rename or move file in remote server after copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631412/spring-integration-sftp-rename-or-move-file-in-remote-server-after-copying?rq=1)
I can solve the issue by change my `InboundChannelAdapter` to `PublishSubscribeChannel` and create new subscriber like below

```java
 @Bean
  @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "streamChannel")
  public MessageHandler moveFile() {
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), Command.MV.getCommand(),
        "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + headers['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway
        .setRenameExpressionString("headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/processed/' +headers['timestamp'] + '-' + headers['file_remoteFile']");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(false);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setUseTemporaryFileName(true);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    sftpOutboundGateway.setAsync(true);
    return sftpOutboundGateway;
  }
```

Comment: If that works, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan That works, I will accept the answer in two days. BTW, I try to move the file that throws an error in the middle(cannot Unmarshalling) by using the same code but changed `inputChannel  = "errorChannel"`. But this does not work and throw [error](https://gist.github.com/keiseithunder/08449418783ac1f9f504fa4287a36610) relate to permission and mkdir. But, the permission seem to be okay because I can run rename and mkdir using sftp cli. Could you please advice this?

Comment: In case you want to see the [updated code](https://github.com/keiseithunder/spring-sftp-xml-to-json/commit/8067ff906761b5fafbc255be21e7e03336764bc4#diff-7fc5821e36cc0a900eb769df1f6d713ed236170907bee582a99fc158b790bcd3)

Comment: I cannot say anything about permissions. Probably check the server side for related errors.

Comment: That is strange because I have tried move file to `upload/processed` folder which I can do it with the code above. The only difference is `inputChannel`  that I change to `errorChannel`. I will open another question then. Since it seem not relate to this.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I just found out that the errorMessage have different structure. So, I need to use difference SpEL expression to access the file path. Eg `payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/error/' + payload['failedMessage']['headers']['timestamp'] + '-' + payload['failedMessage']['headers']['file_remoteFile']`

Answer (score 1):

When you handle an `ErrorMessage`, you should follow a bit different path to get access to the original message and its headers.

We are going to mitigate this inconvenience in the next version: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3984