# Spring SFTP Intergation: processing anmoving file to another directory

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am new to Spring Intergation. I need to process files from sftp server from user1/upload directory and move them to user1/processed drectory after that. My code workes overall ok, but i have two problems:

1. When i restart my application, directory user1/processed is deleted as well as all files that have been there earlier. I want just to write more files there, not to empty directory every time.
2. Every time i start my application i receive files (as i see for their names i print to console) i get old files, thet were already moved to processed directory. It seem really weird, because i cannot see these files when connecting to sftp by some other tools like WinSCP. Are that old file list cashed somewhere?

```
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.host}")
    private String sftpHost;
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.port}")
    private int sftpPort;
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.user}")
    private String sftpUser;
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.pass}")
    private String sftpPasword;
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.remotedir}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload;

    @Value("${cielo.sftp.localdir}")
    private String sftpLocalDirectoryDownload;
    @Value("${cielo.sftp.filter}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectoryDownloadFilter;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);

        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true); //Set to true to allow connections to hosts with unknown (or changed) keys. Its default is 'false'. If false, a pre-populated knownHosts file is required.
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE - 1)
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(final SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory);
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload);
        fileSynchronizer
                .setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownloadFilter)); //todo maybe use RegexPatternFileListFilter?
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE - 2)
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    //@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "${cielo.sftp.poller.cron}"))

    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(final SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer);
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("/tmp/local"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(
            inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler resultFileHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(final Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                String payload = String.valueOf(message.getPayload());
                System.err.println(payload);
            }
        };
    }

    private static final SpelExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();

    @Bean(name="fromSftpChannel")
    public MessageChannel fromSftpChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public MessageHandler moveFile() {
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV.getCommand(), "'/user1/upload/'.concat(" + PARSER.parseExpression("payload.getName()").getExpressionString() + ")");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("'/user1/processed/'.concat(" + PARSER.parseExpression("payload.getName()").getExpressionString() + ")");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(false);
        sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
        sftpOutboundGateway.setAsync(true);
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

Thank for any help!

I looked at example at [Spring integration - SFTP rename or move file in remote server after copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631412/spring-integration-sftp-rename-or-move-file-in-remote-server-after-copying) and that helped me a lot

I also checked official spring intergation sftp documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the remote directory is cleared up on start up. Need to debug that behavior on your side. But I can say you why you see old files. You do remote rename after process, but local copies of those files are still stored on the `source.setLocalDirectory(new File("/tmp/local"));`. Consider to clean up it when you done with renaming or on restart.

You also may look into an `SftpStreamingMessageSource` instead for your logic: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/streaming.html

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the issue with old files in local folder, as you said, it helped. As for remote directory - it seemed it was the result of my previous experiments with sftp intergation, now it works all right. As for SftpStreamingMessageSource - thank you, neext step i will try using it in my logic!